# Multiline TextArea on new lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage that returns information from a database and pre-populates a number of fields including a text area with comma separated information.

Is there something I could do with javascript/jquery to get these values onto seperate lines?

```
<textarea class="multiline" id="textArea1">
foo, foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4, foo5, foo6, foo7, foo8
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have loaded the text in the `textarea`, you can replace the commas with new lines like this:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('textArea1');
textarea.value = textarea.value.replace(/,/g, '\n');
```

If you want to get rid if spaces too you can do this:

```
textarea.value = textarea.value.replace(/, /g, '\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using a regular expression, like this:

**HTML**

```
<textarea class="multiline" id="textArea1">
</textarea>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var text = "foo, foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4, foo5, foo6, foo7, foo8";

text = text.replace(/, /g, "\n");
$("textarea").val(text);
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/w18y5rag/)**

Comment: The `class="multiline"`is not needed. It doesn't mean anything for the browser.

Comment: True, I just copied it from the original question, though I seem to have removed the id attribute... Edit: added the id attribute again.

Comment: Yeah, good point! I have inherited this code so will remove the class :)